# How can I get the real pointer to a field inside a struct in Go?

Tags: go

I have a struct, say:

```
type sample struct{
   data []float64
}
```

Now, I declare a method:

```
func (s sample) Get() *[]float64{
return &s.data
}
```

I am trying to append to this slice via the pointer I got via Get()

```
func main(){
example := sample{[]float64{1,2,3}}

//Here I will append:
pointerToArray := example.Get()
*pointerToArray = append(*pointerToArray, 4)
fmt.Println(example.Get()) // still shows only &{1,2,3}
}
```

I have a general idea of why this is happening: The function Get is returning the address of its local scope, and I have fixed it by change the struct itself to

```
type sample struct{
data *[]float64
}
```

for which the code returns the expected `&{1,2,3,4}`

Now, for my question:
Is there anyway to get the **real** pointer to the field in the struct through a getter method without using a pointer field directly in the struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined the `Get` method with a struct receiver, rather than on a pointer. That means when you return `&s.data` you get the address of the field of receiver, rather than from the original struct. You can fix this simply by using a pointer receiver:

```
func (s *sample) Get() *[]float64{
    return &s.data
}
```

Here's a complete runnable example (https://play.golang.org/p/AIj8QOYfx85)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type sample struct {
    data []float64
}

func (s *sample) Get() *[]float64 {
    return &s.data
}

func main() {
    example := sample{[]float64{1, 2, 3}}

    p := example.Get()
    *p = append(*p, 4)
    fmt.Println(example.Get())
}
```

Comment: Hi, just another question if you could help: If I declare an interface to use this Get() method, how would I make sure that this only accepts pointer reciever types? Like in this example I want to append, but if I define an interface for the same, then how do I make sure that only a pointer reciever method implementation type is accepted?

Comment: You can't. Perhaps better to make the interface `Append(values ...float64)` rather than expose the pointer, assuming you just want to append to it.